# Postgres migration issue 9.6.0 to 9.6.1

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am planning to upgrade our databases from 9.6.0 to 9.6.1 
and I found a problem while upgrading one database that has
many tablespaces. The upgrade  fails with the following error

"Cannot migrate to/from the same system catalog version when using tablespaces"

Comment: you do not need `pg_upgrade` for a minor version upgrade. Just shut down the server, install the binaries into the old location and start the server again